# Missing FilterConfig.h for pcl_ros in Groovy

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using the instructions at http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Source, I am installing ROS on openSUSE 12.3, but I'm running into a snag when it builds the pcl_ros package:

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/abouchard/catkin_ws/build_isolated/pcl_ros
==> make -j2 -l2 in '/home/abouchard/catkin_ws/build_isolated/pcl_ros'
Scanning dependencies of target convert_pcd_to_image
Scanning dependencies of target pcl_ros_tf
[  9%] [  9%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pcl_ros_tf.dir/src/transforms.cpp.o
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/convert_pcd_to_image.dir/tools/convert_pcd_to_image.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable /home/abouchard/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/pcl_ros/lib/pcl_ros/convert_pcd_to_image
[  9%] Built target convert_pcd_to_image
Scanning dependencies of target convert_pointcloud_to_image
[ 13%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/convert_pointcloud_to_image.dir/tools/convert_pointcloud_to_image.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library /home/abouchard/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/pcl_ros/lib/libpcl_ros_tf.so
[ 13%] Built target pcl_ros_tf
Scanning dependencies of target pcd_to_pointcloud
Linking CXX executable /home/abouchard/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/pcl_ros/lib/pcl_ros/convert_pointcloud_to_image
[ 18%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pcd_to_pointcloud.dir/tools/pcd_to_pointcloud.cpp.o
[ 18%] Built target convert_pointcloud_to_image
Scanning dependencies of target pcl_ros_filters
[ 22%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pcl_ros_filters.dir/src/pcl_ros/filters/filter.cpp.o
In file included from /home/abouchard/catkin_ws/src/pcl_ros/src/pcl_ros/filters/filter.cpp:40:0:
/home/abouchard/catkin_ws/src/pcl_ros/include/pcl_ros/filters/filter.h:47:34: fatal error: pcl_ros/FilterConfig.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/pcl_ros_filters.dir/src/pcl_ros/filters/filter.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/pcl_ros_filters.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Linking CXX executable /home/abouchard/catkin_ws/devel_isolated/pcl_ros/lib/pcl_ros/pcd_to_pointcloud
[ 22%] Built target pcd_to_pointcloud
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'pcl_ros': 
  Command '/home/abouchard/catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j2 -l2' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/abouchard/catkin_ws/build_isolated/pcl_ros && /home/abouchard/catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh make -j2 -l2

Command failed, exiting.
```

I looked at filters.h, and it does have an include statement for FilterConfig.h, and it appears that there are several calls to functions in that namespace. I've found versions of the file online, but they appear to be rather dated, and I'm hesitant to just throw a file in there that might allow it to compile but will cause more problems when I try to use it that will make it harder to debug. In any case, the download probably needs to be reconfigured so that this file is included. Is there anyone here with insight into this package that might be able to offer some advice?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81441/missing-filterconfig.h-for-pcl_ros-in-groovy/) by [teddybouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/581/teddybouch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 320 on 2013-09-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-09-20**:
This file should be created because of cfg/Filter.cfg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

change in pcl_ros/CMakeLists.txt the Line

```
add_dependencies(pcl_ros_tf pcl_ros_generate_messages_cpp {catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

to

```
add_dependencies(pcl_ros_tf pcl_ros_generate_messages_cpp {catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg)
```

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2013-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [teddybouch](https://answers.ros.org/users/581/teddybouch/) on 2013-09-20**:
Thanks! The only add_dependencies line that I had was:

add_dependencies(pcl_ros_tf ros_gencpp pcl_ros_copy)

Regardless of the difference, I replaced it with the line you recommended and the package seems to have built successfully!